# any idea how to import mui icon as react component?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to import mui-icon as a component so I can control the name of that icon, since for implantation reasons I want a name that is different that the default name of the icon.

```js
// Default import 
import ViewQuiltIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ViewQuilt';
// Target imput (not working)
import ViewQuiltIcon as somename  from '@material-ui/icons/ViewQuilt';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import AnyName from '@material-ui/icons/ViewQuilt';
```

Have you tried like AnyName?